# redmine 2.1 CSS and JS assets improper url "production/stylesheets"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, passenger

I am having trouble with a new redmine 2.1 setup.

Was working, trying to move over to apache passenger. That took me a few mins to get working but it is running and i can log in.

The problem is that there are no JS/CSS assets being loaded, they all 404.

all assets have urls like this:
/redmine/production/stylesheets/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.21.css?1355946024

That file does not exist, what does exist is 
/redmine/stylesheets/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.21.css?1355946024

Why are all the assets having "/production/" spliced in the middle of the url's?
I am pretty novice to ruby/rails/redmine so i have no idea where to even begin on this one... google was not helpful

Any help is appreciated.